# Jquery div to textbox onclick and back to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you have been on the new PHP myadmin you can click on a field and edit it then when you click away it changes back to a div, I thought this could be found on the web easy but aprently not, so I tryed to make it and I'm not very good with javascript so I failed.
Heres what i got so far.

HTML:

```
<td id="td_1"><input type="hidden" value="0" />0</td>
```

Javascipt:

```
$("#td_1").click(function() {
    $input = $("#td_1");
    $field = $('<input type="text" id="txt_1" maxlength="1" size="1"/>').attr({
        id: $input.id,
        name: $input.name,
        value: $input.val()
    });
    $input.after($field).remove();
});
```

It adds the textbox but does not add the value to it, and stuck on how to change it back

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Check out the [`contenteditable` attribute](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/#browser-support) in HTML5. It may help: `<div id="example-one" contenteditable="true">CLICK AND EDIT ME</div>`.

Comment: Couldn't you leave the div there and just add the textbox inside (moving the text from the div to the textbox)? `$("#myDiv").html="<textarea id="myTextbox">"+$("#myDiv").text+"</textarea>";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would have a hidden textbox that you show when you click on the text value. **[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q22tG/)**

**HTML**

```
<td id="td_1"><input id="txtBox" type="textbox" value="0" style="display:none;" /><span id="txtBoxValue">0</span></td>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtBoxValue').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide(); //hide text
        $('#txtBox').show(); //show textbox
    });

    $('#txtBox').on('blur', function() {
        var that = $(this);
        $('#txtBoxValue').text(that.val()).show(); //updated text value and show text
        that.hide(); //hide textbox
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a quick question, why use the function() at the start, wont it work without it and just have it between document ready?

Comment: yea nice try, just to 1 span and 1 input, but if we have to many of them?

Comment: @user1977434 Check out the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Comment: @Logar314159 Good point, though that wasn't included in the original question. It wouldn't be too hard to do if you used naming conventions with naming conventions for the ID's. Or you could get the parent of the text field and find the closest text box...

Answer (score 3):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vcZT), it works on multiple `span`'s and `input`'s.

```
<div class="editDIV">
    <span class="editESPAN" style="display:block;">asd</span>
    <input class="editINPUT" style="display:none;" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="editDIV">
    <span class="editESPAN" style="display:block;">asd</span>
    <input class="editINPUT" style="display:none;" type="text"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

$(".editDIV").click(function(){
    $(this).find("span")[0].style.display="none";
    $(this).find("input")[0].style.display="block";
    $(this).find("input")[0].focus();
});

$(".editINPUT").blur(function(){
    $(this)[0].style.display="none";
    $(this).prev()[0].innerText=$(this)[0].value;
    $(this).prev().show();
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#td_1").click(function() {
    $input = $("#td_1");
    $field = $('<input type="text" id="txt_1" maxlength="1" size="1"/>').attr({
        id: $input.id,
        name: $input.name,
        value: $input.text()
    });
    $input.after($field).remove();
});
```

Comment: Use `$input.text()` instead of `$input.val()`